# Bash select ignore space

Tags: bash, ubuntu

So I'm trying to create a bash script that does something for every file in a directory. This is my script. The problem is that this script split on each space i would rather have it split on new line. So it look just like ls print. (I'm going to put other code inside the do, the echo is just a test)

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in $(ls)
do
    echo $file
done
```

So how do i solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd better avoid working with the result of `ls` ([Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Instead, do something like:

```
for file in /your/dir/*
do
   echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: ok thx, just one more problem. Your code printed - as â how do i fix this?

Comment: Mmmm that's very weird. You mean there is a file called `-` that gets printed as `â`?

Comment: I got a file that contains - like this "file 122-134" and when i use the script i get "file 122â134"

Comment: ok never mind seems like ls does the same thing. So it's not the script.

Answer (score 0):

To pick files only:

```
while read -r file; do
    echo "$file"
done < <(exec find -xtype f -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1)
```

Or just filter them

```
for file in *; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    echo "$file"
done
```